# Django: Logging to custom files every day

Tags: django, logging

I'm running Django 3.1 on Docker and I want to log to different files everyday. I have a couple of crons running and also celery tasks. I don't want to log to one file because a lot of processes will be writing and debugging/reading the file will be difficult.

If I have cron tasks my_cron_1, my_cron_2,my_cron_3
I want to be able to log to a file and append the date

```
MyCron1_2020-12-14.log
MyCron2_2020-12-14.log
MyCron3_2020-12-14.log

MyCron1_2020-12-15.log
MyCron2_2020-12-15.log
MyCron3_2020-12-15.log

MyCron1_2020-12-16.log
MyCron2_2020-12-16.log
MyCron3_2020-12-16.log
```

Basically, I want to be able to pass in a name to a function that will write to a log file.

Right now I have a class `MyLogger`

```
import logging    


class MyLogger:

    def __init__(self,filename):

        # Gets or creates a logger
        self._filename = filename


    def log(self,message):
        message = str(message)

        print(message)

        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)  

        # set log level
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # define file handler and set formatter
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler('logs/'+self._filename+'.log')
        #formatter    = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(message)s')
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        # add file handler to logger
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        # Logs
        logger.info(message)
```

I call the class like this

```
logger = MyLogger("FirstLogFile_2020-12-14")
logger.log("ONE")

logger1 = MyLogger("SecondLogFile_2020-12-14")
logger1.log("TWO")
```

`FirstLogFile_2020-12-14` will have ONE TWO but it should only have ONE
`SecondLogFile_2020-12-14` will have TWO

Why is this? Why are the logs being written to the incorrect file? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you reinventing [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler)?